# How to get largest file in directory in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a following question. In variable `DIR` there is unknown number of files and folders. I would like to get the name and size in bytes of the largest one in following order: name size. For example: `file.txt 124`.

I tried:

```sh
cd $DIR
du  -a * | sort | head -1
```

But it does not show the size in bytes, and it is in size name format. How can I improve it please?

Comment: Do you have the `-b` flag?

Comment: i don't want `-h` because it will return size in human format. I want bytes.

Comment: Have a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/524764/27653

Comment: ( `du -ab` or `du -ak` ) `| sort -n` ...  or `du -ah | sort -h` ....

Comment: @F.Hauri Sorry, but no. I really need output `file.txt 124`. That is file name, space, and number of bytes.

Comment: @vojtam It works for files but not dirs (and probably files with `\n` in the filename), that's why I deleted it (this: `ls -S | head -1 | xargs -d \\n stat -c "%n %s" `).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`ls -larS | awk -F' {1,}' 'END{print $NF," ",$5}'`

LS long listing reverse sort by Size, then Awk prints the last field $NF, and the 5th field, using a single space or multiple single spaces, as the field separator, of the last line, being the largest size (due to reverse sort order above).

Edit:

It was mentioned a space in the file name might cause an issue, my first suggestion, is dont use spaces in filenames, it is just plain wrong, but if you have to:

`ls -larS | awk -F' {1,}' 'END{for (i=9; i<=NF; i++) printf $i" "; print " ",$5}'`

will handle the space, or two, or three, or how ever many

Comment: ` ls -larS | awk -F' {1,}' 'END{for (i=9; i<=NF; i++) printf $i" "; print " ",$5}'`

That fixes that

Comment: So it seems. Nice. Also, spot on with the suggestion but what can you do...

Answer (score 1):

What about the following pipeline? I'm using GNU findutils and GNU coreutils. If you work on a Mac you might have to install them.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s %f\0' \
  | sort -z -k1,1nr \
  | head -zn1 \
  | cut -zd' ' -f2-
```

**Explanation:**

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s %f\0'
```

Find files in the current folder and print them along with their filesize in bytes, zero terminated. Zero terminated because filenames may contain newlines in UNIX.

```
sort -z -k1,1nr
```

Sort the listing by the filesize in bytes, column 1, in reverse order  (largest first). -z reads input zero terminated.

```
head -zn1
```

prints the first item, which is the largest, after the previous sorting. -z reads input zero terminated

```
cut -zd' ' -f2-
```

Cut off the filesize, print only the filename. -z reads input zero terminated.

Comment: @rowboat good point, thanks! Added `-z`

Answer (score 0):

A variation which should produce the exact output requested:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f %s\0" \
  | sort -znr -k2 \
  | head -zn1 \
  | tr "\0" "\n"
```